# What is the CAKeyframeAnimation equivalent of CABasicAnimation's fromValue and toValue

Tags: cabasicanimation, cakeyframeanimation

The CABasicAnimation properties fromValue and toValue make it easy to animate a path, starting from an arbitrary point in the path and lasting for an arbitrary duration. I haven't found an equivalent way to do the same in CAKeyframeAnimation. Alternatively, how can CABasicAnimation be used to animate a path taken from another layer, considering that CABasicAnimation has no path property? (At the moment I am using UIBezierPath, but I suppose the same answer would apply to CGMutablePathRef.)

Comment: You can supply an array of `values`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks David, but unfortunately if you use a path, as I am, you cannot use an array of values.

Comment: So change the path depending on the to and from values. Without knowing how your path is created and how it relates to the to and from values, there isn't enough information to answer your question.

Comment: The paths are fixed and made up of anywhere from 5-20 segments of unequal lengths. In the end, I created an invisible path beneath the visible one and used a combination of CABasicAnimation with strokeEnd to capture the time at which the path's end has been reached. At that point I remove the keyframe animation using a generated key, which was my objective.